# Clock signal becomes noisier at higher frequencies

Tags: fpga, oscilloscope

I am sending the clock signal of a DE0-Nano FPGA to one of its GPIO pins. As I increase the frequency, the signal becomes more and more distorted. Is this an issue with the GPIO pins having small buffers? My scope has a bandwidth of 200MHz and my probes are also rated for 200MHz. What might be the reason for this?

Ultimately I want to modulate data on top of this clock signal.

1) Is there a way I can output a clean clock signal at a high frequency like 100MHz?

2) Can I modulate a clean square wave of data on top of this clock signal?

**10kHz**

[image]

**100kHz**

[image]

**1MHz**

[image]

**10MHz**

[image]

**100MHz**

[image]

Comment: Quick test: run all the signals at 20 ns/div and look at the rising edge.  I bet they all look the same.

Comment: What type of modulation?

Comment: Your question is not how to output the clock, but how to correctly capture it. Please look up the Nyquist sampling theorem - you will learn that to see a clean 100 MHz signal with likely 1-ns edges, you would need at least a 500-MHz or 1 GHz scope, with at least 2 Gsps sampling rate.

Comment: My scope samples at 1GS/s and is rated to have a bandwidth of 200MHz

Comment: For the modulation I want to output either a low or high voltage for every rising clock edge.

Comment: Are you using a x10 probe setting?

Comment: And what kind of I/O buffer do you use on your Altera Cyclon IV particular pin?

Comment: Oh not again!, I again fell for user2562609...

Comment: Get a TEK7904 analog scope, and see truth.

Comment: You have 200MHz scope, it can still display 200MHz **sine** wave properly.
Nnow you have a 100MHz **square** wave. It will have a period of 1/100MHz=10ns. So, to have something looking like a square wave (not too much like a trapezoid), the rise time will have to be significantly shorter, for example 1ns.
The fastest component of you signal is not 100MHz but 1/1ns=1GHz.
Your scope measures some voltages and tries to interpolate a signal curve from it and it **will** be wrong (see Nyquist). If you zoom out on the time axis (slow clock) you won't see the errors, but if you zoom in, you will.

Answer (score 1):

Fist, a 200 MHz oscilloscope and a 200 MHz probe will only give you a system bandwidth of 141 MHz (ish).

We talk about calculating "system bandwidth" on our blog here:
https://community.keysight.com/community/keysight-blogs/oscilloscopes/blog/2016/09/01/what-is-oscilloscope-system-bandwidth-and-how-do-i-find-the-bandwidth-of-the-scope-probe

Basically, the bandwidths compound.

Second, a bandwidth of 141 MHz means you can a 141 MHz sine wave with 3dB or less of attenuation. So, for a 100 MHz clock, it's not going to look like a square wave.

This app note actually looks at **a 100 MHz clock example on page 7** and talks about how to evaluate your oscilloscope's bandwidth for your app.

http://literature.cdn.keysight.com/litweb/pdf/5989-5733EN.pdf

The ringing you're seeing is probably some inductive or capacitive effects of your probing system.